# Difference between `warble executable war` vs `bundle exec warble executable war`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, jruby, warbler

I am trying to package a Rails application to a WAR file. I am pre-compiling the assets, then using warbler to package the application to a WAR file.

Pre-compile:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Now im trying to package the Rails application to a WAR file using the command:

```
warble executable war
```

What is the main difference between the above command and the below command:

```
bundle exec warble executable war
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bundle exec warble executable war
```

`bundle exec` will make sure it is using the gem version mentioned in `Gemfile`